# How to read Gmails using the api?

Tags: python, flask, nlp, gmail-api, session-variables

so I was able to put a code together that allows me to retrieve unread messages from last 48 hours , thanks to @LindaLawton-DaImTo.

here, I'm having problems to prettify the output (which is in a html format). I tried to put a html code but that doesn't work, any help ?

codes are attached below...

```
# Import necessary modules and packages
import os
import pathlib
import requests
import base64
import email
from flask import Flask, session, abort, redirect, request, render_template
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow
from pip._vendor import cachecontrol
import google.auth.transport.requests
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


# Initialize Flask application
app = Flask("Google Login App")

# Set a secret key for session management
app.secret_key = "msassignment"

# Set an environment variable to allow insecure transport for testing purposes
os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

# Define Google Client ID and path to client secrets file
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = "595198401971-f90dig00k3o1eak45d6m5c9098jm3pet.apps.googleusercontent.com"
client_secrets_file = os.path.join(
    pathlib.Path(__file__).parent, "credentials.json")

# Initialize OAuth flow with necessary scopes and redirect URI
flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    client_secrets_file=client_secrets_file,
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
            "openid"
            ],
    redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:5000/callback"
)


# Decorator function to check if user is logged in
def login_is_required(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if "google_id" not in session:
            return abort(401)  # Authorization required
        else:
            return function()

    return wrapper



def ListMessages(credentials):
    emails = []

    try:
        # Calculate the cutoff date (48 hours ago from now)
        cutoff_date = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=48)
        cutoff_date_str = cutoff_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

        # Create a gmail service object
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

        # Define the query to get unread messages from the last 48 
        print(cutoff_date_str)
        query = f"is:unread after:{cutoff_date_str}"

        # Call the Gmail v1 API with the specified query
        results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q=query).execute()
        messages = results.get('messages', [])

        if not messages:
            print('No messages were found.')
            return

        for message in messages:
            email_info = getMessage(credentials, message['id'])
            emails.append(email_info)

        print("emails retrived successfully")
        print(emails) 

    except HttpError as error:
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


def getMessage(credentials, message_id):

    email_info = {}

    try:
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

        # Call the Gmail v1 API, retrieve message data.
        message = service.users().messages().get(
            userId='me', id=message_id, format='raw').execute()

        # Parse the raw message.
        mime_msg = email.message_from_bytes(
            base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw']))

        email_info['from'] = mime_msg['from']
        email_info['to'] = mime_msg['to']
        email_info['subject'] = mime_msg['subject']

        # Find full message body
        message_main_type = mime_msg.get_content_maintype()
        if message_main_type == 'multipart':
            for part in mime_msg.get_payload():
                if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
                    email_info['body'] = part.get_payload()
        elif message_main_type == 'text':
            email_info['body'] = mime_msg.get_payload()

        return email_info

    except Exception as error:
        print(f'A message get error occurred: {error}')
        return email_info




# Route for initiating the login process
@app.route("/login")
def login():
    # Get authorization URL and state from the OAuth flow
    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url()
    # Store state in the session
    session["state"] = state
    # Redirect user to the authorization URL
    return redirect(authorization_url)


# Route for handling callback after successful authentication
@app.route("/callback")
def callback():
    # Fetch the token using the authorization response from the URL
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=request.url)
    # Check if the state in the session matches the state in the request arguments
    if not session["state"] == request.args["state"]:
        abort(500)  # State does not match! Abort with a 500 error.
    # Get the credentials from the OAuth flow
    credentials = flow.credentials
    # Set up a session for making requests
    request_session = requests.session()
    # Create a cached session to store requests
    cached_session = cachecontrol.CacheControl(request_session)
    # Create a token request using the cached session
    token_request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request(
        session=cached_session)
    # Verify the ID token to get user information
    id_info = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(
        id_token=credentials._id_token,
        request=token_request,
        audience=GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
    )
    # Store user information in the session
    session["google_id"] = id_info.get("sub")
    session["name"] = id_info.get("name")
    # Redirect the user to the protected area
    return redirect("/protected_area")


# Route for logging out
@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    # Clear the session
    session.clear()
    # Redirect user to the homepage
    return redirect("/")


# Route for the homepage
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


# Route for the protected area, requires login
@app.route("/protected_area")
@login_is_required
def protected_area():
    credentials = flow.credentials
    emails = ListMessages(credentials)
    return render_template("emails.html", emails=emails)


# Run the application if executed directly
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this is emails.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Unread Emails</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Unread Emails</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for email in emails %}
            <li> 
                <p>Subject: {{ email.subject }}</p>
                <p>Body: {{ email.body }}</p>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try doing a message get on one of the messages returns in the list.

Comment: hi @LindaLawton-DaImTo, if you don't mind could you please elaborate on that ?

Comment: check my answer i went and grabbed yo some code from one of the samples I have

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo, i have successfully retrieved unread emails from last 48hours. Only the output is not in the readable format. Im trying to prettify it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  version notice how i use list messages then do a get on each message.  And the `format='raw'`

```
def ListMessages(credentials):

    try:
        # create a gmail service object
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

        # Call the Gmail v1 API
        results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()
        messages = results.get('messages', [])

        if not messages:
            print('No messages where found.')
            return
        print('Messages:')
        for message in messages:
            getMessage(credentials, message['id'])
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


def getMessage(credentials, message_id):
    # get a message
    try:
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

        # Call the Gmail v1 API, retrieve message data.
        message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message_id, format='raw').execute()

        # Parse the raw message.
        mime_msg = email.message_from_bytes(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw']))

        print(mime_msg['from'])
        print(mime_msg['to'])
        print(mime_msg['subject'])

        print("----------------------------------------------------")
        # Find full message body
        message_main_type = mime_msg.get_content_maintype()
        if message_main_type == 'multipart':
            for part in mime_msg.get_payload():
                if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
                    print(part.get_payload())
        elif message_main_type == 'text':
            print(mime_msg.get_payload())
        print("----------------------------------------------------")

        # Message snippet only.
        # print('Message snippet: %s' % message['snippet'])
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print(f'A message get error occurred: {error}')
```